# Changing imported R function globally

Tags: r, dbplyr, tbl

I want to globally add a parameter to a function after import. So in future function calls the function should be always called with the set parameter. 
In this case, I want to add the function parameter in_schema("abc") to the function tbl from dplyr.

Normally, I would use the source code and modify the function parameters, save and source it. But in this case, I am already failing to get a proper source code file.

```
getAnywhere("tbl.DBIConnection")
```

> A single object matching 'tbl.DBIConnection' was found
>   It was found in the following places
>    registered S3 method for tbl from namespace dplyr
>    namespace:dplyr
>   with value
>
> ```
> function (src, from, ...) 
> {
>     check_dbplyr()
>     tbl(dbplyr::src_dbi(src, auto_disconnect = FALSE), from = from, 
>         ...)
> }
> ```

How could I modify the tbl-function (in a script file) so future calls always use a certain Scheme?

like so:

```
tbl(connection, table, in_schema("abc"))
```

without having to provide the in_schema parameter all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't copy and modify the function, it's messy, do something like this instead :

```
tbl_abc <- function(src, from, ...){
  tbl(src, in_schema("abc", from), ...)
}
```

btw `tbl(connection, table, in_schema("abc"))` is improper syntax, `in_schema("abc")` needs a second argument, and it's passed to the `...`, which are not used by `tbl.DBIConnection()`

Comment: Thanks, also for the hint about in_schema; It works! I edited it to: tbl_dwh <- function(from, src = SOURCE,  ...){
  tbl(src, in_schema("abc, from), ...)
}